# How to disable typescript linting in nuxt3?

Tags: typescript, jsx, eslint, nuxtjs3

In my `nuxt3` project I want to use `jsx` to create dynamic virtual dom. To achieve that I used
by following [this example](https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/advanced/jsx) given in offical doc.

```
<script lang='tsx' setup>
    ...
</script>
```

by setting `lang='tsx'` also enable `typescript linting` which is annoying as I want to use JavaScript only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use typescript, just use `lang=jsx`